# Simulation of wireless communication system

Tags: digital-communications

In monte carlo simulation of the wireless communications system why we multiply noise by SNRlin( Signal to Noise Ratio in linear). What is the logic behind doing this. Any help in this basic doubt is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more details and an example as to what you are referring to exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to change the noise power, keeping signal power same, thus effective changing the SNR. If you keep the signal to unit power and modify the variance of noise in accordance with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{SNR}}$. You would effectively get the desired SNR for the  received signal. In Monte Carlo simulations this is done many times for a fixed SNR to get the average bit error rate for that SNR point. Usually there would be a loop over SNR as well to simulate for different SNR points.

You could acheive the same thing by keeping the noise to be unit varainace and multiple by $\sqrt{SNR}$ to the signal part.

We use the linear scale because that is how the SNR actually impacts reception. The receiver signal model is linear in signal and noise.

Sample code:

> $$y = signal + \frac{randn(1,1)}{\sqrt{SNR}}$$
>
> Or
>
> $$y = \sqrt{SNR}*signal + randn(1,1)$$

Both have signal to noise ratio as SNR

Comment: @ Dsp guy, can u give a small matlab code as example for your explanation.

Comment: @Charu added to the answer

Comment: guy,i understood the code and your explanation. But how the variance of noise gets modified in accordance with 1/sqrt(SNR).

Comment: @charu, by reasoning the higher the SNR, the lesser the impact of noise, so if you model the signal power to remain constant then the noise power has to be reduced as in the expression above. The power of signal of signal is $E(signal^2)$ and the power of noise is $\frac{1}{SNR}E(randn(1,1)^2)$. Since the randn is unit variance is unit variance and we assume signal power to be a constant, 1. Then taking the ratio of signal to noise power equals SNR, which is what it should be